# $L_\infty[0,1]$ completness and separability

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Prove that $L_\infty[0,1]$ with the norm given by
>
> $$\Vert f\Vert_\infty:= \inf\{S(N): \mu(N)=0\}, \quad \mbox{where}
>  \quad S(N)=\sup\{|f(x)|: x\notin N\}.$$
>
> is complete and is not separable.

I wasn't able to find an uncountable family of functions $(f_i:[0,1] \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ such that $\Vert f_i \Vert_\infty= 1$ to prove that $L_\infty[0,1]$ is not separable.

And I need a hint to prove the completness. Can anybody help me?

Comment: about the separability: try to use a diagonal method. Given a dense numerable set, find a function that is far from the set

Comment: http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4400/h13/undervisningsmateriale/l-infty.pdf

for completeness

Comment: @Ilham, thank you very much!

Comment: **HINT** For completness prove that any Cauchy sequence admits a convergent subsequence. To negate separabilty, prove that for any numerable subset $A=\{a_1, a_2, \cdots \}$, there exist $f \in L^\infty$ such that $\|f-a_k\|>1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín, i understood the idea, but I was not able to write it down =/

Comment: Ok, I'm posting an answer proving that $L_\infty$ is not separable, since I am assuming you got the completness part from @Ilham comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*$L_\infty[0,1]$ is not separable*

**PROOF**  Assume that $L_\infty[0, 1]$ 
is separable. Now consider the set 
$$
F= \{ f_t : f_t(x)= \chi_{(0,t)} (x)  \ \ t \in (0,1) \} 
$$
Since all the $f_t$ are measurable and clearly $\|f_t\|_\infty=1<\infty$, then $F\subset L_\infty[0,1]$. Of course since $(0,1)$ is uncountable,  **$F$ is also uncountable**.

Since $L_\infty[0, 1]$ is separable there exist a **countable subset $A=\{ a_1, a_2, \cdots \}\subset L_\infty[0,1]$** such that $\overline{A} = L_\infty[0,1]$. Take any  $f_t \in F \subset \overline{A}$, and for $\varepsilon=1/2$ choose $a \in A$ such that $\| f_t-a\|_\infty < 1/2$. Then for $t' \neq t$
$$
1=\|f_t-f_t' \|_\infty \leq \|f_t-a\|_\infty + \|a-f_t' \|_\infty < 1/2 + \|a-f_t' \|_\infty
$$
which gives that $ 1/2 + \|a-f_t'\|_\infty>1  \Longrightarrow \|a-f_t' \|_\infty>1/2$. Thus for every $f_t \in F$ there exist only and only one $a \in A$ such $\| f_t-a\|_\infty < 1/2$, that is $F$ and a subset of $A$ have the same elements, but since $F$ is uncountable, $A$ must be uncountable, **a contradiction.** $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ {\blacksquare}$

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't define the set F as you did, I was thinking in a set way more strange.

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad to help. Sorry that on my Hint in the first comment I gave a different approach of the one that I used here, I was thinking on a diagonal argument to prove that $\ell_\infty$ is not separable, in the end this are all valid proofs of the fact that $L_\infty(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is not separable.

Comment: I was trying to use the same idea of the proof for the space $l_\infty$, thanks for helping me with this! =D

Comment: No problem. For $\ell_\infty$ use the diagonal argument as I told you before. If you have any problems you can tell me, or post another question. Good luck.